# Ionic scroll delegate: reset scroll position after navbar click

Tags: scroll, ionic-framework

I don't know what is happening, but I post this here cause maybe I have a mistake, not Ionic.

So here is the problem: after change scroll view I push at navbar and scroll position resets at `{left: 0, top: 0}`. Zoom params doesn't change.

Here is an example I made:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PPVjry

How can I fix it if it possible?

P.S. I didn't find any github issues or anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens with lists too.  Try adding this to your ion-nav-bar element:

```
no-tap-scroll="true"
```

Here is the [reference](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavBar/).